# How to get network printer serial number

Tags: python, printing

for particular needs, the program I am creating will have to print only on a specific printer. The only unique identifier I can think of is the serial number. For this reason, I would like to be able to read the serial number of the printer, which is connected via ethernet.

I found some directions for a command from PowerShell

`Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Printer | Select-Object SerialNumber`

which however returns something empty, without information.
I also found a Python library win32print, which allows me to get the list of printers configured on the PC with related additional information, with the exception of the serial.
Suggestions on alternative unique identification methods are welcome.
I'm using Python, and the printer is a TOSHIBA eStudio 5005ac
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not use the MAC-address (the physical address of the printer network adapter) for this?